# java.io.NotSerializableException: androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, serialization

I just started running into an error that I just don't understand. I'm making a note editor app and the resulting error occurs after I try to save my data in the editor activity. Usually, this save method works just fine but in this particular context it causes an issue.

Here are the related code blocks:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NoteEditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int noteId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);

        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.et_NoteText);
        EditText editTitle = findViewById(R.id.et_NoteTitle);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        noteId = intent.getIntExtra("noteId", -1);

        editText.setText(State.St.st_current.getNote(noteId).getText());
        editTitle.setText(State.St.st_current.getNote(noteId).getTitle());

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                UpdateText(charSequence);
            }

        });

        editTitle.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                UpdateTitle(String.valueOf(charSequence));
            }
        });
    }

    private void UpdateText(CharSequence text){
        State.St.st_current.getNote(noteId).setText(text);
    }

    private void UpdateTitle(String title){
        State.St.st_current.getNote(noteId).setTitle(title);
    }

    private void BackUp(){
        Utility.ManageData.SaveState(getApplicationContext(), State.St);
    }
}
```

```
public class Utility {
    public static class ManageData {

        public static void SaveState(Context context, State state){
            String dir = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
            dir += "/state";
            File path = new File(dir);
            try{
                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
                ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);
                objectOut.writeObject(state);
                outStream.close();
                objectOut.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static State LoadState(Context context) {
            String dir = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
            dir += "/state";
            File path = new File(dir);
            try {
                FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(path);
                ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
                State state = (State) objectIn.readObject();
                inStream.close();
                objectIn.close();
                return state;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class State implements Serializable {

    public static State St;

    public ArrayList<Bubble> st_bubbles;
    public Bubble st_current;

    public State(){
        st_bubbles = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Bubble> getBubbles() { return st_bubbles; }
    public Bubble getBubble(String name) {
        for(int i = 0; i < st_bubbles.size(); i ++){
            if(st_bubbles.get(i).getName().equals(name)) return st_bubbles.get(i);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Also all contained objects are also serializable.

And here are all the related error codes.

2022-07-12 07:20:57.196 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err: java.io.NotSerializableException: androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder
2022-07-12 07:20:57.196 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.196 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.196 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.196 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:762)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1036)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1552)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.197 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.198 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.198 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
2022-07-12 07:20:57.198 28080-28080/com.learn.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.learn.myapplication.Utility$ManageData.SaveState(Utility.java:34)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Something about saving the text as a CharSequence instead of a String was causing the error. If someone has an explanation as to why that would be an issue that would be fantastic.

```
package com.learn.myapplication;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Note implements Serializable {

    private String nt_title;
    private CharSequence nt_text; // Changed to String
    private final String nt_created;
    private Bubble nt_bubble;

    public Note(Context context, Bubble bubble){
        this.nt_bubble = bubble;
        this.nt_created = Utility.DateAndTimeNow();
        this.nt_serial = ReturnSerial(context);
        this.nt_title = "";
        this.nt_text = "";
    }

    public Note(Context context, Bubble bubble, CharSequence text){ //Changed to String
        this.nt_bubble = bubble;
        this.nt_created = Utility.DateAndTimeNow();
        this.nt_serial = ReturnSerial(context);
        this.nt_title = "";
        this.nt_text = text;
    }

    public String getTitle(){ return nt_title; }

    public CharSequence getText(){ return nt_text; } // Changed To String

    public String getCreated(){ return nt_created; }

    public Bubble getBubble(){ return nt_bubble; }

    public boolean setTitle(String title){ this.nt_title = title; return true;}

    public boolean setText(CharSequence text){ this.nt_text = text; return true;}

    public boolean setBubble(Bubble bubble){ this.nt_bubble = bubble; return true; }

}
```